# R get all categories in column

Tags: r, categories, datacolumn

I have a large Dataset (dataframe) where I want to find the number and the names of my cartegories in a column.

For example my df was like that:

```
 A   B   
 1   car
 2   car
 3   bus
 4   car
 5   plane 
 6   plane 
 7   plane 
 8   plane 
 9   plane 
 10   train
```

I would want to find :

```
  car
  bus
  plane
  train
  4
```

How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with `number and names`? What number? For instance, where does the 4 come from? If you mean frequencies, you may want to use something like `table(df$B)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
categories <- unique(yourDataFrame$yourColumn) 
numberOfCategories <- length(categories)
```

Pretty painless.

Answer (score 12):

This gives unique, length of unique, and frequency:

```
table(df$B)
bus   car plane train 
1     3     5     1

length(table(x$B))
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use unique:

```
x <- unique(df$B)
```

And it will extract the unique values in the column. You can use it with apply to get them from each column too!

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use factors here, if you are not already.  It's straightforward and simple.

`levels()` gives the unique categories and `nlevels()` gives the number of them.  If we run `droplevels()` on the data first, we take care of any levels that may no longer be in the data.

```
with(droplevels(df), list(levels = levels(B), nlevels = nlevels(B)))
# $levels
# [1] "bus"   "car"   "plane" "train"
#
# $nlevels
# [1] 4
```

Comment: Thankfully there's a data frame method for `droplevels`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, to see sorted values you can use the following:

```
sort(table(df$B), decreasing = TRUE)
```

And you will see the values in the decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must ensure that your column is in the correct data type. Most probably R had read it in as a '*chr*' which you can check with '*str(df)*'.
For the data you have provided as an example, you will want to change this to a '*factor*'. df$column <- as.factor(df$column)
Once the data is in the correct format, you can then use '*levels(df$column)*' to get a summary of levels you have in the dataset